# Transition filling in table instead of Button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create similar effect found here: 
codepen.io/davekilljoy/pen/wHAvb?editors=010

The first button effect to be more specific. I followed most instructions, and added in a few changes to make it fill in from the left instead. 
For some reason when I hover over it, it fills in the whole table instead of just the button. I want it to start from the beginning of the button to the end, not from the beginning of the table to the end.
Here's a crappy quality GIF so you get the idea of what's happening now: http://i.imgur.com/vz5TTjy.gif

This is the CSS:

```
        #nav {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            left: -20px;
        }

        #nav ul {

            list-style-type: none;
        }

        #nav ul li button {
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #383736;
            letter-spacing:2px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            overflow: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: 0;
            background: none;
            background: white;
            border: 1px solid #383736;
            border-radius: 3px;
            padding: 7px 12px;
            margin: 35px 0px;
            z-index: 1;
            -webkit-transition: 0.08s ease-in;
        }

        #nav ul li button:hover {
            color: white;
        }

        #nav ul li button::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid white;
            background-color: #383736;
            right: 100%;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            z-index: -1;
            -webkit-transition: right 0.15s ease;
        }

        #nav ul li button:hover:before {
            right:0;
        }
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><button>About Me</button></li>
        <li><button>Links</button></li>
        <li><button>Contact Me</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set button in position:relative so pseudo use it as reference.

```css
        #nav {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            left: -20px;
        }

        #nav ul {

            list-style-type: none;
        }

        #nav ul li button {
          position:relative;
            font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #383736;
            letter-spacing:2px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            overflow: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline: 0;
            background: none;
            background: white;
            border: 1px solid #383736;
            border-radius: 3px;
            padding: 7px 12px;
            margin: 35px 0px;
            z-index: 1;
            -webkit-transition: 0.08s ease-in;
        }

        #nav ul li button:hover {
            color: white;
        }

        #nav ul li button::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid white;
            background-color: #383736;
            right: 100%;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            z-index: -1;
            transition: right 0.15s ease;
        }

        #nav ul li button:hover:before {
            right:0;
        }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><button>About Me</button></li>
        <li><button>Links</button></li>
        <li><button>Contact Me</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Makes a lot of sense now. If I took out the first bit of code, where I set the #nav position to relative, it would go over the whole background instead. Now I understand why :)